# do I add 'exec bash -l' to .cshrc to have bash default shell for ssh session? (or what)

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scp, csh

I want to default to bash (or zsh) in my ssh sessions, so I tried adding `exec bash -l` to a shell profile that I know is being accessed: .cshrc.

This appeared to work, but my trial-and-error ways are coming back to haunt me.  The command `scp me@host:file .` only works when I remove the `exec bash -l` line.

Is this the right way to login to a bash shell, or should I do something else?  Perhaps a local solution in my actual `ssh me@host` call.

If the specific errors are relevant I'll paste them in an edit, but I suspect the problem is I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: First, you are mentioning scp AND ssh. I guess you mean only ssh? Second, you just say "it does not work". With only this information, we can't give much help. Finally, you didn't say in which place of your .cshrc you have inserted the *exec bash*. In any case, while debugging this, you should better do `exec bash -x -l` and analyse the outcome.

Comment: exec bash -l at the end of my .cshrc profile (obviously).  I DO mean scp, since ssh works fine.  scp issues an error when trying to copy 'file' from the remote host to local.  It doesn't do so when I remove the exec bash -l.  I think the question is answered already though.

Comment: I am surprised that scp would cause .cshrc to be executed. It needs to authorize you on the remote host, but it doesn't need to run any shell at all....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`chsh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) command to change your default login shell.

Print the list of shells available:

```
chsh -l
```

Change default shell:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash <username>
```

Get the default login shell of the current user:

```
getent passwd <username> | cut -d: -f7
```

Comment: oh! that worked.  And putting this into .cshrc is good practice if I want to change shells on login?

Comment: No. It is a bad way to achieve this.

Comment: what do I do instead?

Comment: It is not possible to force ssh to use other shell than your default shell. But if you want to run bash script though ssh try: http://serverfault.com/a/162035/204896 or `ssh $IP 'bash -s ' < yourscript`

Comment: I've looked at this again and found that it only works because of the error "$ chsh /bin/bash
chsh: user '/bin/bash' does not exist".  so maybe this isn't the answer for me after all.

Comment: I have modified teh answer to be more precise.

Comment: @7171u: See the response of Alejandro to my above comment. It seems that Alejandro is not worried about ssh, but of scp. Confusing....